# Why I need to tap twice a GMSMarker when it is overlapping a GMSOverlay to show its info window?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-markers, gmsmapview

I have an **GMSOverlay** in a GMSMapView, so I listen to taps into it with the method:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap overlay: GMSOverlay) {
    // Overlay was tapped
}
```

Then I want a **GMSMarker** to be painted over the GMSOverlay, and I listen to taps into it with the method:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {
    // Marker was tapped
    return false
}
```

Every time the listener of the marker is called, its info window hides (if it's shown) or shows (if it's hidden).

The problem is that **the listener of the marker is not called every time I tap it**.

Step by step:

1. Tap in the marker:

   - The info window **shows** because the listener of the marker is called.
   - The listener of the overlay is not called.
2. Tap in the marker:

   - The info window **doesn't hides** (it should) because the listener of the marker is not called.
   - The listener of the overlay is called (it shouldn't).
3. Tap in the marker:

   - The info window **hides** because the listener of the marker is called.
   - The listener of the overlay is not called.
4. Tap in the marker:

   - The info window **doesn't show** (it should) because the listener of the marker is not called.
   - The listener of the overlay is called (it shouldn't).
5. Tap in the marker: step 1.
6. Tap in the marker: step 2.
7. Tap in the marker: step 3.
8. Tap in the marker: step 4.

... and so on ...

In brief:

### After the first tap, I need to tap two times the marker to hide or show the info window.

[image]

Comment: I know its late but I also faced same type of issue and solved it. Please take a look https://stackoverflow.com/a/65857592/2637953